# Failing when casting to DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this CSV

```
"06/04/2016 17:24:14,1443.92,0.31"
```

Which I try to convert into the following object

```
public class FooModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Change { get; set; }
}
```

with the following code

```
    string[] values = line.Split(',');
    FooModel m = new FooModel
    {
        Date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Time = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Index = values[1],
        Change = values[2],
    };
```

and failing on the exception

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How can I cast to `DateTime` Object

**EDIT**

I saw couple of answers that almost worked however it was my bad to mention that the date is formatted as Day-Month-Year. this means that it is failing when the csv is set to "22/12/2014 16:24:04,1476.83,-0.74"

Comment: Neither of those formats exactly match your string.  Instead use a format that matches the entire thing and use the `Date` and `TimeOfDay` properties of `DateTime` to get the date an time components.  Note that time really should be stored as a `TimeSpan` and not a `DateTime`.  Or better yet just have one `DateTime` property in your `FooModel`.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess the issue you're having is with the Parse*Exact* part of this.

Why are you converting both the date and the time separately? It seems easier to do this:

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(values[0]);
string time = Date.ToLongTimeString();
string date = Date.ToLongDateString();
```

This way it's saved in the same variable and you can use the pieces as you need.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

The input string is:

```
"06/04/2016 17:24:14,1443.92,0.31"
```

The format string is:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Those aren't really *exact*.  Just use `Parse` instead:

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(values[0]);
```

This gives you the complete `DateTime` value, so you don't even need the `Time` property on the model.  No need to store the same information twice, after all.

Additionally, you might use `TryParse` to be a little safer with the input:

```
DateTime temp;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(values[0], out temp))
{
    // parsing error.  notify the user?
}
Date = temp;
```

Comment: The problem is that it switches between the Day and Month, and failing with exception when Date is "30/12/2014 16:24:04,1476.83,-0.74"

Comment: @user829174: Is the format from a known culture?  You might be able to specify it in `TryParse`.  Something like: `DateTime.TryParse(values[0], CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out temp)` but just replace `"en-US"` with the desired culture.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, How can I tell if this is a known culture?

Answer (score 0):

When you split the string values[0] = 06/04/2016 17:24:14 and you are parsing the Date and the Time component separately. Instead you need to parse them together with

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and access the date by

```
date.Date
```

and access the time by

```
date.Time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] s = "06/04/2016 17:24:14,1443.92,0.31".Split(',');
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(s[0]);
```

This worked for me.